# How can we avoid calling a service each time a recursive component, in which it is provided, is instantiated?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

Here is a typical component that has `FormService` in providers:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-block",
  templateUrl: "./block.component.html",
  styles: ['.block_children { padding-left: 50px;}'],
  providers: [FormService]
})
export class BlockComponent {
  constructor(@Host() public formService: FormService) {}

  @Input() form: any;

  getType(form: any) {
      console.log(typeof form);
  }
}
```

If the app builds the component recursively it always creates a new instance of `FormService`. How can this be avoided?

```
<app-block [form]="form" *ngFor="let form of formService.roots()"></app-block>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `@Injectable` is provided at the component level, it is instantiated every time the component is created.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to provide the `FormService` in the `NgModule` instead of on the `Component`. However, if you need a `FormService` per group of these things, then you would want to create a container component to provide the `FormService` a dom level above this component.

To create one `FormService` for the entire app, make your `app.module.ts` file look like this (note ellipsis are used here to indicate other code):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ...],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  providers: [FormService, ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Of course you can also provide the FormService at the Feature Module level... but we are keeping it simple here.

The documentation describes how the dependency injector "finds" the service more clearly here: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: Solution is to add service in  app.modules?

Comment: I have tried to move in   `providers: [FormService]` inside app.module. it still calls constructor of service some times

Comment: Without `@Injectable()` I get error: ` Can't resolve all parameters for FormService: (?)`

Comment: Did you remove the `providers: [FormService]` from the component? I think that is the reason it keeps getting instantiated.

Comment: Yes, I have removed

Comment: What does the service look like?

Answer (score 2):

So, and correct me if Im wrong, but angular should handle this for you. Adding the service in the constructor doesn't instantiate a new instance of that service, but gives you a pointer to a single existing instance of that service

- I apologize its been a little since Ive worked in angular. But I remember having conversations about how angular manages services. It should only create a single instance of each service that are shared throughout the project. Why do you think that your creating multiple instances of your formService?

Comment: It will create because service is provided in component. You are right if and only if service is providing in module. So the solution is providing it on a module which component declared.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you're say. They are declaring the service with the @Self() public syntax ?

Comment: I have tried to move in providers: [FormService] inside app.module. it still calls constructor of service some times

Comment: @OPV you can see my example and check console to understand how many times the service is provided https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chvf4r